# jQuery can't select element by attribute name and get the nodename

Tags: jquery, select, attributes, nodename

I am trying to select this element by attribute name and print the nodename, but the result is undefined.

The first alert works, but the second alert doesn't work.

HTML code:

```
<objeto bordeactivo type="image">

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354"/>

</objeto>
```

jQuery code:

```
var ob = $("[bordeactivo]");
var ob2 = ob.find("img");

// Works!
alert("ob>"+ob.attr("type"));

// NOT WORKING!
alert("nodeName>"+ob2.nodeName);
```

What is the problem?

My JsFiddle:

[jsfiddle code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/shjytg75/12/)

Comment: Hi, try `ob2[0].nodeName` like this and see if that works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `ob2.prop("nodeName")`, you can access the DOM property **nodeName** of the underlying `<img>` element and display it in the alert box.

#### Try below Code

```js
var ob = $("[bordeactivo]");
var ob2 = ob.find("img");

// Works
console.log("ob>" + ob.attr("type"));

// Updated code
console.log("nodeName>" + ob2.prop("nodeName"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<objeto bordeactivo type="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" />
</objeto>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the prop() method.